# Passing a set of numbers

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am trying to compute some mathematical formulas using SQL, but I've stumbled upon the problem of holding k numbers. How could I hold them in a simple way, so I can access them directly, without actually declaring each one of them as individual variables? I've thought about using arrays, but it would be a bit too complicated, is there anything simpler?

The code I've tried with distinct variables to hold the numbers: https://pastebin.com/mPvKCiNP

```
v_sum := v_first + v_second + v_third;
```

Instead of this line, have something like a while and iterate through all the values. I don't necessarily need to know the number of values, since I can always pass it through parameters.

Comment: Your question is too abstract.  Can you provide sample data desired results, and the logic you are trying to achieve (perhaps all simplified)?

Comment: Yes, so, I am trying to make a function which takes as parameters a list, array, something to hold values and I want to compute their mean and display it. So, my question is, how can I actually give the numbers into the function, without calling the function "mean(first_number, second_number, ...)"? Is there a way of doing something like "mean(all_numbers)", and inside the function, just do a while loop, from 1 to number of elements, and access each number from the "all_numbers" that was sent as parameters, sum them in a variable (v_sum), and make the mean?

Comment: . . That doesn't seem "SQL-ish".  SQL holds such numbers in a table and you don't need a function to calculate the average -- one is already available (`avg()`).  There are ways to define  your own aggregation functions.  And, PL/SQL supports constructs such as arrays which can be passed into functions.  I think you are trying to do something inappropriate.  SQL is not an object-oriented programming language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `table` type represents an unbounded array (not to be confused with relational data tables).

```
create or replace type number_table_type is table of number;

create or replace procedure mean (number_table_type nt) as
v_sum number := 0;
begin
    for i IN nt.first..nt.last loop
        v_sum := v_sum + i;
    end loop;
    [...]
end mean;
```

You can declare an instance of your table type:

```
nt number_table_type := number_table__type(1, 2, 3, 4);
```

Comment: Instead of a loop you can also run `select sum(column_value) from table(nt)`

Comment: It must be the opposite, i.e. `create or replace procedure mean (nt IN number_table_type) as` (though `IN` is default and can be skipped)